# what happens to my documents in Google Drive when a connected app on is no longer available?

Tags: google-drive

Lets say I connect an app to Google Drive.  For example Code Your Cloud from https://codeyourcloud.com.  This app lets you edit C# code in Google Documents.

My question is what happens to my existing documents if that service goes away?  I understand the data is saved in my Google drive, but the service is no longer available, so I will not be able to open those files any more?

Or are these externally created apps still hosted on Google servers? Is there a guarantee that you can still open your files when/if that app is no longer maintained or the company disappears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Code Your Cloud saves all its code/documents as a .txt file, a file extension that Google Drive can open, you'll be able to retrieve all the data you created with Code Your Cloud.

However, since Google Drive doesn't have native support for editing .txt files, you have two choices after that if you want to *edit*, not just view.

1. Use another text editor (through linking the app or downloading the Drive desktop app and using a desktop editor).
2. Copy all your code and paste it into a Google Drive-native format. This is the more cumbersome method, and arguably the less compatible one.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that unless Code Your Cloud saves in a proprietary format, no. If the service disappears, you can still use what you've created using it.

With Code your Cloud in particular, even if they die and the file format is proprietary, their code is open source and up on GitHub, so you could reverse engineer your way into opening your files.